# Querying and grouping by date (Y/m/j) when date is in a Y/m/j H:i:s format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have a table called tablex with the following attributes:

1. timestamp
2. eventid

timestamp is of format Y/m/j H:i:s
E.g. 2015/02/20 00:19:16

There are many events per day.

I am generating charts and I need to formulate my SQL query to get date VS count of events for the past 30 days.

```
SELECT COUNT(eventid)
FROM `tablex`
WHERE timestamp //this is the part where I'm stuck.
GROUP BY DAY(timestamp)
```

Or is it advisable to create another attribute only with date Y/m/j? Or can it be done via SQL query?

Comment: What is the data type of `timestamp`?

Comment: the timestamp is of type - varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `timestamp` is a date/time column -- which it should be.  You should not be storing date/times as strings.  Then you can do:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp), COUNT(eventid)
FROM `tablex`
WHERE timestamp >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 30 day)
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

Note that this query includes the date in the `select`.

If your timestamp is stored as a string, it is in a sort-of reasonable format.  I would be inclined to translate it using a subquery and just use that.

```
SELECT thedate, COUNT(eventid)
FROM (select x.*, date(replace(left(timestamp, '/', '-'), 10) as thedate
      from `tablex` x
     ) x
WHERE thedate >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 30 day)
GROUP BY thedate;
```

Note that you can also use `str_to_date()` to convert the string to a date.  I just find it easier in this case to use `date()` and `replace()`.

Comment: i switched the timestamp to date/time column. i am able to query now.